# Where does Facebook store friendship information?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, friends

If I am friends with someone, I can see when we became friends on the activity timeline, if I unfriend him, I can no longer see when we first became friends, if I add him again, I can see both the first and the second time that I added him, my question is, where is this information stored? it seems to me like Facebook still keeps these interactions between two accounts, is there a way to see when I became friends with someone that I'm no longer friends with?